# Request to Spring Boot Application Local vs Prod

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application without property `server.servlet.context-path` configured in my application.yml.
For access anyone endpoint local (dev), I make a request without context path.

Example:

> curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/foo/bar'

Now think so, we have the context path or application with name `app`.

In the production environment I need to make the request with the context path.
Example:

> curl --location --request GET 'http://server.com/**app**/foo/bar'

I have already configured environment in Postman:

| ENVIRONMENT | VARIABLE | CURRENT VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOCAL | host | http://localhost:8080 |
| PROD | host | http://server.com |

To make the request in Postman, I use:

`LOCAL: {{host}}/foo/bar`

`PROD: {{host}}/app/foo/bar` <-- See that here I need pass the context path.

I would like  to change the environment from Postman without add or remove the context path name of request.
Something as optional variable for context path.
Someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `/app` path in your Production Environment {{host}} variable, and keep same paths when switching between environments.

Comment: I don't want it that way, as I use {{host}} for other apps

Comment: you can always use {{prefix}} which will be empty for Dev/Local and "/app" for Production